# RODBC Error for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - is there a list of acceptable keywords?

Tags: r, rodbc

I submitted a simple (so I thought) query via `RODBC` :

```
ch <- odbcConnect(dsn.name, believeNRows=FALSE, rows_at_time=1)
sqlQuery(ch, "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()")
```

And it threw the following error:

```
[1] "42000? -1 Malformed SQL Statement: Unrecognized keyword: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP\r\nStatement:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()"
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()'"
```

I thought `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` is a common SQL command and didn't expect this to not run. I had checked that the ODBC connection (RSSBus DynamicsCRM Source x64) supports `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`. My connection is OK, I was able to perform some other SQL queries.

So is there a problem with my syntax above? Or is there a list of keywords that `RODBC` doesn't recognise?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`?

Comment: See my comment to Rajeev's reply below

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, first line i.e.

`ch <- odbcConnect(dsn.name, believeNRows=FALSE, rows_at_time=1)`

creates a connection to your ODBC data source name (dsn.name). So here `ch` basically stores the connection instance. The second line:

`sqlQuery(ch, "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()")`

executes the SQL query on the connection i.e. `ch` and returns the result in a data frame. So instead of using the method `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` use complete query:

`sqlQuery(ch, "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()")`

I hope this will help.

Comment: I actually tried the query with `SELECT` earlier, but got this error `[1] "HY000 -1 The EntitySet attribute is null or empty"                  
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()'"` hence why I tried without `SELECT` and thought the root problem is unrecognised keyword.

In any case, I'm still interested to find out how to execute this.